# How to convert a html, css, js template into a template for hugo static website builder

Tags: templates, hugo

Is it possible to use a regular HTML (with css and js) template inside the Hugo static website builder? 
If not, is there a way to convert it in order to be usable?
Thank you!

Comment: The only thing hugo does is having certain keywords which are then automaticly replaced by something else once you build the website, you may use any html or css in hugo, infact, you could just put everything in the "static" directory and hugo would do nothing more than move the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You have at least two options:

**option 1**

If the file is named e.g. foo.html, copy it as `static/html/foo.html`. It will be served as `example.com/static/html/foo.html`.

Very simple, but you don't get any help from hugo at all.

**option 2**

You can integrate it into the hugo a bit.

1. Copy the file to content/html/foo.html.
2. Add front matter to the file. At a minimum add two lines of '---' to the top.
3. create a default layout in layout/_default/html.html. It will simply contain ...

   {{ .Content }}

This has the advantage of also automatically generating a page that lists all such pages.